# XmlSerializer Converts newlines

Tags: c#, winforms, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize an object to memory, pass it to another process as a string, and deserialize it.

I've discovered that the XML Serialization process strips the \r off of the newlines for strings in the object.

```
byte[] b;
// serialize to memory.
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
    xml.Serialize(ms, this);
    b = ms.GetBuffer();
}

// I can now send the bytes to my process.
Process(b);

// On the other end, I use:
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b))
{
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
    clone = (myObject)xml.Deserialize(ms);
}
```

How do I serialize an object without serializing it to disk just like this, but without mangling the newlines in the strings?

Comment: Exactly which newlines are stripped?

Comment: in myObjcet, I have several strings, each of which can contain newlines.

Comment: Also, do you have control over the classes being serialized? Are the two processes both running .NET? If so, you have much better options.

Comment: Yes. They are both .NET. I know I could go field-by-field and put things back, but that's not what I'm hoping for. I'm hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: I was thinking you should use WCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came from anther SO post, but I'm reposting it here because I had to tweak it a little.

I had to create a new class to manage XML read/write to memory stream. Here it is:

```
public class SafeXmlSerializer : XmlSerializer
{
    public SafeXmlSerializer(Type type) : base(type) { }

    public new void Serialize(StreamWriter stream, object o)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
        ws.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize;

        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, ws))
        {
            base.Serialize(xmlWriter, o);
        }
    }
}
```

Since it is built on top of XmlSerializer, it should behave exactly as expected. It's just that when I serialize with a StreamWriter, I will use the "safe" version of the serialization, thus saving myself the headache.

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The strings should be wrapped in CDATA sections to preserve the newlines.

Comment: Note that he serializes his objects to produce the XML - you need to tell him how to _put_ the strings into CDATA sections.